# Get current HTML from browser tab with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I know there are plenty ways to get a HTML source passing the page url.
But is there a way to get the current html of a page if it displays data after some action ?

For example: A simple html page with a button (thats the source html) that displays random data when you click it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a tool collectively known as a "headless browser". The only one I've used that is available in Python (and can vouch for) is Selenium WebDriver, but there are plenty to choose from if you're searching up headless browsers for Python.

https://pypi.org/project/selenium

With this you should be able to programmatically load a web page, look up and click the button in the virtually rendered DOM, then lookup the innerHTML property of the targeted element.